# NodeJS, Mongoose - How to define a recursive model in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I'm implementing GraphQL with Mongoose.

In the `typedef.js`, I specified the Channel structure like this:

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-server-express';

export const Channel = gql`
type Channel {
    "Name of the channel, this is the full path."
    name: String!
    parent: Channel
    children: [Channel]!
}
`
```

It's clear that when I defining the model `Channel`, I also used it as the data structure of its elements.

And I would like to know how to write the `model` of it in mongoose.

What I'm writing now is like this:

```
//models/Channel.js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
export const Channel = mongoose.model('Channel',
    {   
        name: String,
        parent: String,
        children: [String]
    });
```

Which I don't think is correct.

**Note: I'm writing in ES6 of Javascript.**

Comment: what should a channel document in database look like ?

Comment: @grodzi I should look like a treeNode, with parent and children nodes specified.

Comment: you are not explicit enough for me. Should it look like ```{name:'s', children:[{name:'b', children:[{name:'c', children:[]}, {name:'d', children:[]}]}]}``` or ```{name:'s', children:[0000...00, 0000...01]}``` where ```0000...00``` and ```0000...01``` are ObjectId's of some ```Channel``` document, or something else ?

Comment: @grodzi Yes, I think this structure makes sense!